# MVVM WPF C# - Combobox binding foreign key FormatException

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, binding

I have two entities: *Client* and *Manager*.
Code for them is:

```
public partial class Manager
{
  public Manager()
  {
    this.Clients = new HashSet<Client>();
  }
            
  public int Id_manager { get; set; }
  public string Name_manag { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Client> Clients { get; set; }
}

public partial class Client
{
  public Client()
  {}       
  public int Id_cl { get; set; }
  public int Manager { get; set; }  
  public virtual Manager Manager1 { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel class has this code:

```
 private ObservableCollection<Manager> _managerList;
 public ObservableCollection<Manager> ManagerList
        {
            get { return _managerList; }
            set
            {
                _managerList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ManagerList");
            }
        }
```

On my view i have combobox, where i can choose a client manager.
Also i have a DataGrid, which shows the list of clients.

I binded ComboBox with this XML code:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbManager" 
          Margin="5"
          Padding="3"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ManagerList}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name_manag"
          SelectedValuePath="Id_manager"
          SelectedValue="Binding Manager1.Id_manager"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Manager1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

So the problem is - when i open my **view**, i get an exception :

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 
    System.Number.StringToNumber(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, ref System.Number.NumberBuffer, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo, bool)
    System.Number.ParseInt32(string, System.Globalization.NumberStyles, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo)
    string.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(System.IFormatProvider)
    System.Convert.ChangeType(object, System.Type, System.IFormatProvider)
    MS.Internal.Data.SystemConvertConverter.Convert(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
    MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter.Convert(object, System.Type, object, System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.VerifyEqual(object, System.Type, object, MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.FindItemWithValue(object, out int)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectItemWithValue(object, bool)
    System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
```

I binded my ComboBox incorrectly, so help me to write correct bind.

Comment: `"Binding Manager1.Id_manager"` is not a valid Binding expression. It misses the parentheses. Besides that, it is unclear why you think you need to bind both SelectItem and SelectValue at the same time. And for `"{Binding Manager1.Id_manager}"` you would need a `Manager1` property in your view model class. Finally, all properties that change their value need to fire a change notification, e.g. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: Ha-ha, omg. Thank u so much! You opened my eyes! I missed parentheses and that was the problem. Now programm works fine !